# Why does reading from STDOUT work?

Tags: qt, unix, stdout, stdin, pty

I encountered a curious case, where reading from STDOUT works, when running a program in terminal. The question is, why and how? Let's start with code:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QSocketNotifier>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QByteArray>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    const int fd_arg = (a.arguments().length()>=2) ? a.arguments().at(1).toInt() : 0;
    qDebug() << "reading from fd" << fd_arg;

    QSocketNotifier n(fd_arg, QSocketNotifier::Read);

    QObject::connect(&n, &QSocketNotifier::activated, [](int fd) {
        char buf[1024];
        auto len = ::read(fd, buf, sizeof buf);
        if (len < 0) { qDebug() << "fd" << fd << "read error:" << errno; qApp->quit(); }
        else if (len == 0)  { qDebug() << "fd" << fd << "done"; qApp->quit(); }
        else {
            QByteArray data(buf, len);
            qDebug() << "fd" << fd << "data" << data.length() << data.trimmed();
        }
    });

    return a.exec();
}
```

Here's *qmake* .pro file for convenience, if someone wants to test above code:

```
QT       += core
QT       -= gui
CONFIG += c++11
TARGET = stdoutreadtest
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

And here's output of 4 executions:

```
$ ./stdoutreadtest 0 # input from keyboard, ^D ends, works as expected
reading from fd 0
typtyptyp
fd 0 data 10 "typtyptyp"
fd 0 done
```

---

```
$ echo pipe | ./stdoutreadtest 0 # input from pipe, works as expected
reading from fd 0
fd 0 data 5 "pipe"
fd 0 done
```

---

```
$ ./stdoutreadtest 1 # input from keyboard, ^D ends, works!?
reading from fd 1
typtyp
fd 1 data 7 "typtyp"
fd 1 done
```

---

```
$ echo pipe | ./stdoutreadtest 1 # input from pipe, still reads keyboard!?
reading from fd 1
typtyp
fd 1 data 7 "typtyp"
fd 1 done
```

So, the question is, what is going on, why do the last two runs above actually read what is typed on terminal?

I also tried looking at QSocketNotifier sources [here](http://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/kernel/qsocketnotifier.cpp.html) leading to [here](http://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/kernel/qeventdispatcher_unix.cpp.html#401), but didn't really gain any insight.

Comment: Take a look at the symlinks in /proc/$pid/fds/ -  1 is just a symlinks to the TTY if you do nothing else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no different between fd 0,1,2, all of the three fds is pointing to terminal if not redirected, they are strictly IDENTICAL!

Programs usually use 0 for input, 1 for output, 2 for error, but all of them can be different ways.

Eg, for `less`, ordinary usage:

```
prog | less
```

Now input of `less` is redirected to the `prog`, and `less` can not read any user input from `stdin`, so how does `less` get user input like scroll up/down or page up/down ?

Sure `less` can read user input from stdout, which is exactly what `less` does.

So you can use these fds wisely when you know how bash handle these fds.